# Hyperparameter Tuning Invalid parameter lr for estimator KerasRegressor

Tags: python, keras

```py
# Import
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```

Code (in the Error section):

It looks like I'm going to try to fix it for a while now. The problem seems to be in the `grid_result`, and I'm not sure if the issue is with the code itself or with the `KerasRegressor` that I imported.

```py
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_autoencoder, verbose=0)

param_grid = dict(batch_size=b, epochs=e, optimizer=optimizer, lr=learning_rates)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, n_jobs=1, verbose=10, cv=2, param_grid=param_grid)

grid_result = grid.fit(train_x_noise, train_x)

best_params = grid_result.best_params_
best_score = grid_result.best_score_

means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']

# Display the results
print(f'Best params: {best_params}')
print(f'Best score: {best_score}')

for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

No matter how I try to fix it, I keep getting the same error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-a32022928fc8> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, n_jobs=1, verbose=10, cv=2, param_grid=param_grid)
      6 
----> 7 grid_result = grid.fit(train_x_noise, train_x)
      8 
      9 best_params = grid_result.best_params_

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in set_params(self, **params)

ValueError: Invalid parameter lr for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(lr=0.1)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()
```

I've been trying to fix it for a while now, but I don't know where it's stuck.

Comment: ## *Error* 
```
----> 7 grid_result = grid.fit(train_x_noise, train_x)
```

Comment: Replace the parameter 'lr' in param_grid with 'learning_rate' and give it a try. Please inform about the result of the change.